# AWS EC2 Windows Server 2016 expose port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, windows-server, windows-server-2016

What I'm trying to do is access my webserver on my EC2 from the outside.

Here's what I've done so far:

- I've opened all Incoming Traffic to anywhere both for IPv4 and IPv6 in the EC2's Security group
- Disabled the firewall from the Control Panel in the EC2 for both public and private
- Started my webserver on port 80

From outside the ec2:

- I can ping the EC2 succesfully
- If I run `telnet <my ec2 ip> 80` I get `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`
- If I run `nmap <my ec2 ip>` port 80 is not listed

From inside the ec2:

- I was able to connect from localhost:80 in EC2's browser
- If I ran `netstat -aon` it shows it is listening on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your web server is bound to the external network interface.

Using `0.0.0.0` will ensure that connections can be made from any interface. On the other hand, using `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`) would have behavior like what you describe, where you can connect to the web server locally, you can reach the host externally (e.g. via `ping`) but cannot connect to the web server externally.

Comment: Proto   Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    127.0.0.1:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1716
TCP    [::1]:80               [::]:0                 LISTENING       1716

Answer (score 0):

Is your EC2 instance in a custom VPC?  If so, look at attaching an Internet Gateway to the VPC and update the route tables associated with the subnet in which your instance is running.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not very knowledgeable about VPCs I'm using the default VPC that AWS provided, could that still cause issues? In what way could a VPC block port 80?

Comment: I assume you still had to create a subnet in the default VPC, or are you using EC2-Classic?  With a default VPC, you should need to still attach an Internet Gateway.  Go to your VPC Dashboard and select Internet Gateways from the left-hand menu.  Then attach an Internet Gateway to the default VPC.  You will also need to create a subnet and update its associated route table by adding a route to the new Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I am assuming that you are using IIS as your web server.

1) Start Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

2) Expand the left hand panel "Connections" and locate your web server under "Sites".

3) Select your web site. In the right hand panel click on "Bindings".

4) A "Site Bindings" dialog box will open.

5) Under the tab "IP Address" make sure that an asterisk displays so that the server binds to all network interfaces on startup.

5) In the right hand panel under "Manage Website" click "Restart".

Comment: >_> not using IIS since I'm making an API for a class project just a Web API core 2 project using ASP.NET Development Server which ships with Visual Studio